# Why doesn't my BroadcastReceiver receive broadcasts from another app?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

App A has this BroadcastReceiver in its manifest (within <application>):

And this receiver:

```
public class RemoteControl extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Log.w(TAG, "Look what I did!");
  }
}
```

I'm trying to trigger this from App B:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  Log.w(TAG, "Sending stuff");
  Intent i = new Intent("app.a.remotecontrol");
  i.setData("http://test/url");
  sendBroadcast(i);
}
```

For whatever reason, the onReceive() in App A is never triggered even though it's broadcasted from App B.  What can be the cause of this?

EDIT & **SOLUTION**: I forgot to write that I used setData() on the Intent before broadcasting it.  That was indeed the problem:  as soon as I removed setData(), the broadcast worked as intended.

Comment: Strange. The code looks fine.

Comment: It does to me too.  This is frustrating.

Comment: Try adding <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> to the intent filter

Comment: ognian: I though that was the problem, but alas!  I've updated the question with the solution:  I used setData() on the Intent, which somehow blocks it from being sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally I forgot to write that I used setData() on the Intent before broadcasting it.  That was indeed the problem: as soon as I removed setData(), the broadcast worked as intended.

I've switched to use putExtra() instead for the Intent metadata:

```
Intent i = new Intent("app.a.remotecontrol");
i.putExtra("url", "http://test/url");
sendBroadcast(i);
```